LaTeX: Text type
I'm looking for the package that allows me to write the characters in my document the same way as in the photo below.

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Chorus}% Set main font

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs,tikz,times,pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur} % Bibliothèque pour les ombres

\newcommand\circitem[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    \node[circle,draw=gray, fill=white!85, % Couleur plus vive
    minimum size=1.2em,inner sep=0] (char) {#1};}}
\newcommand\boxitem[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    \node[fill=blue!10,
    minimum size=1.2em,inner sep=0] (char) {#1};}}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\protect\circitem{\arabic*}}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\protect\boxitem{\alph*}}

\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{exa}[2][]{enhanced,breakable,before skip=2mm,after skip=5mm,
  colback=white!50!white, % Fond plus vif
  colframe=blue!50, % Bordure plus vive
  boxrule=0.5mm,
  attach boxed title to top left ={xshift=0.6cm,yshift*=1mm-\tcboxedtitleheight},
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  title={#2},#1,
  boxed title style={frame code={
      \path[fill=blue!30,blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5}] % Effet d'ombre
      ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=-1mm]frame.north west)
      arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=1mm]
      ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=1mm]frame.north east)
      arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=1mm];
      \path[left color=blue,right color = blue!60!black,
      middle color = blue]
      ([xshift=-2mm]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=2mm]frame.north east)
      [rounded corners=1mm]-- ([xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north east)
      -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west)
      -- ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north west)
      [sharp corners]-- cycle;
    },interior engine=empty,
},interior style={top color=white!10!white, bottom color=white!50!white}} % Dégradé de couleur



\begin{document}

\vskip2cm

\begin{exa}[colbacktitle=blue!85]{Exercice 1}
    Dans $\mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{R})$, on considère le sous-ensemble :

    $$
    E = \left\{M(x) = \begin{pmatrix}
        x & x \\
        0 & 0
    \end{pmatrix} / x \in \mathbb{R}\right\}, \text{ On pose : } E^* = E - \{M(0)\}
    $$
\end{exa}

\end{document}

\usepackage{tgchorus} does not affect the character style of my document.


https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture

You are loading times which will overwrite the setting of \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Chorus}. And you definitely shouldn't be loading fontenc and inputenc with Unicode engines.

Somebody discovered Zapf Chancery in the font menu in Word and thought it was funny to use it. It isn't and such a font is completely out of place in a serious piece of work such as an examination paper. Don't imitate it: the font is meant to be decorative and is painful for long reading.

@egreg Ok, thank you so much

While I wouldn't use serious as @egreg did, the font is definitely inappropriate here. If this is for an exam paper - or any use in teaching which is not (1) short and (2) deliberately non-academic in appearance - it's horrible. Worse, I imagine this will cause students with some specific learning disabilities (e.g. dyslexia) entirely unnecessary difficulty. It is also likely to cause trouble for students with certain kinds of visual impairments. Please don't go out of your way to make materials inaccessible.

You have done a mix of fonts and used "contestually" the engines XeLaTeX and pdfLaTeX. I have fixed also a bit your code. Double $$ are deprecated. \usepackage{tgchorus} work correctly.

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tgchorus}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs,tikz,pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur} % Bibliothèque pour les ombres

\newcommand\circitem[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    \node[circle,draw=gray, fill=white!85, % Couleur plus vive
    minimum size=1.2em,inner sep=0] (char) {#1};}}
\newcommand\boxitem[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    \node[fill=blue!10,
    minimum size=1.2em,inner sep=0] (char) {#1};}}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\protect\circitem{\arabic*}}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\protect\boxitem{\alph*}}

\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{exa}[2][]{enhanced,breakable,before skip=2mm,after skip=5mm,
  colback=white!50!white, % Fond plus vif
  colframe=blue!50, % Bordure plus vive
  boxrule=0.5mm,
  attach boxed title to top left ={xshift=0.6cm,yshift*=1mm-\tcboxedtitleheight},
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  title={#2},#1,
  boxed title style={frame code={
      \path[fill=blue!30,blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5}] % Effet d'ombre
      ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=-1mm]frame.north west)
      arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=1mm]
      ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=1mm]frame.north east)
      arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=1mm];
      \path[left color=blue,right color = blue!60!black,
      middle color = blue]
      ([xshift=-2mm]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=2mm]frame.north east)
      [rounded corners=1mm]-- ([xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north east)
      -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west)
      -- ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north west)
      [sharp corners]-- cycle;
    },interior engine=empty,
},interior style={top color=white!10!white, bottom color=white!50!white}} % Dégradé de couleur

\begin{document}

\vskip2cm

\begin{exa}[colbacktitle=blue!85]{Exercice 1}
    Dans $\mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{R})$, on considère le sous-ensemble :

  \[
    E = \left\{M(x) = \begin{pmatrix}
        x & x \\
        0 & 0
    \end{pmatrix} \mid x \in \mathbb{R}\right\}, \text{ On pose : } E^* = E - \{M(0)\}
  \]
\end{exa}

\end{document}

